# Unsupported Operation Exception from Jetty ManagedSelector

Tags: android, ssl, jetty, embedded-jetty

I'm trying to run Jetty server with TLS-PSK. However, I am receiving the following log msg:

```
WARN org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector - java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
```

Jetty logs shows is enabled below:

```
+> Cipher Suite Selections
   +> Enabled size=1
   |  +> TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
   +> Disabled size=24
```

When I start my Jetty server on Android, the following is the dump log related to Selector

```
+= SelectorManager@ServerConnector@fe6bfb2{SSL, (ssl, http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:8443} - STARTED
|  += ManagedSelector@7ad0eac{STARTED} id=0 keys=0 selected=0 updates=0 - STARTED
|     += EatWhatYouKill@42fd775/SelectorProducer@582930a/PRODUCING/p=false/QueuedThreadPool[qtp207014042]@c56c89a{STARTED,8<=8<=10,i=6,r=-1,q=0}[ReservedThreadExecutor@9540b03{s=0/1,p=0}][pc=0,pic=0,pec=0,epc=0]@2021-09-08T01:32:00.463-04:00 - STARTED
|     |  +- SelectorProducer@582930a
|     |  +~ QueuedThreadPool[qtp207014042]@c56c89a{STARTED,8<=8<=10,i=6,r=-1,q=0}[ReservedThreadExecutor@9540b03{s=0/1,p=0}] - STARTED
|     +> updates @ 2021-09-08T01:32:00.453-04:00 size=0
|     +> keys @ 2021-09-08T01:32:00.46-04:00 size=0
```

Below is the list of SslContextFactory API configuration I called so far:

```
QueuedThreadPool threadPool = new QueuedThreadPool();
threadPool.setMaxThreads(10);

Server jettyServer = new Server(threadPool);
jettyServer.addBean(new ScheduledExecutorScheduler());

SslContextFactory ctxFactory = new SslContextFactory.Server();
ctxFactory.setProvider(PROVIDER_NAME);
ctxFactory.setKeyStoreProvider(PROVIDER_NAME);
ctxFactory.setExcludeCipherSuites(new String[0]); //Empty
ctxFactory.setIncludeCipherSuites(suites); //"TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA"
ctxFactory.setExcludeProtocols("TLS", "TLSv1", "TLSv1.1");
ctxFactory.setIncludeProtocols("TLSv1.2");
ctxFactory.setKeyStore(keystore);
ctxFactory.setSslContext(sslContext);
```

Is there some configuration I'm missing with regards to Selector?

Comment: Not enough information provided to work with.  What is PROVIDER_NAME? What Android API level are you working with? What is the entire stacktrace of that exception?

Answer (score 0):

Your chosen `PROVIDER_NAME` does not implement the java `SSLEngine` API completely, or properly.

See: https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/4961